# One-liner to count number of occurrences of String in a String[] in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array of `String`:

```
String[] myArray = {"A", "B", "B", "C"};
```

Is there a quick way to count the number of occurrences of a string in that array? Yes, I know I can iterate and do the count myself:

```
int count = 0;
String whatToFind = "B";
for (String s : myArray) {
    if (s.equals(whatToFind)) {
        ++count;
    }
}
```

But I was wondering if there was a utility function for this. I couldn't find anything in `Arrays` or `ArrayUtils`. Is it possible to do this with a one-liner?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java count occurrence of each item in an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098601/java-count-occurrence-of-each-item-in-an-array)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You can use [the `frequency` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#frequency%28java.util.Collection,%20java.lang.Object%29):

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(myArray);
int count = Collections.frequency(list, "B");
```

or in one line:

```
int count = Collections.frequency(Arrays.asList(myArray), "B");
```

---

With Java 8 you can also write:

```
long count = Arrays.stream(myArray).filter(s -> "B".equals(s)).count();
```

Or with a method reference:

```
long count = Arrays.stream(myArray).filter("B"::equals).count();
```

Comment: Neat! Didn't know that one. +1

Comment: @assylias Good answer need to remember this one

Comment: @RohitJain It is a matter of taste I suppose - added the one-liner version for you!

Answer (score 2):

You can also try using [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) which is full of useful utilities. Using below code, you can count the frequency via [Multiset](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multiset):

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
        String[] myArray = {"A", "B", "B", "C"};
        Multiset<String> wordsMultiset = HashMultiset.create();
        wordsMultiset.addAll(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(myArray)));
        int counts=wordsMultiset.count("B");
        System.out.println(counts);
    }
```

Although I know that you are looking for a single liner, but Guava is full of many more utils which are not possible with routine java utils.

Comment: You can make it a one-liner with: `int count = HashMultiset.create(Arrays.asList(myArray)).count("B");` ;-)