# Number of occurrences in array

Tags: java, arrays, find-occurrences

Logic please..  With just using for or while loop...
Example:

```
int a[ ]  = {2,3,2,3,4,4,5,1,3};
```

Output :

```
2 occurred 2 time
3 occurred 3 time
4 occurred 2 time
5 occurred 1 time
1 occurred 1 time
```

Comment: You'd probably be better served by figuring this out yourself, but to get you started... why don't you look at each number in turn and save a running total of how many times you've seen each number?  Lots of data structures to help you with this... look for a Map structure in your language of choice (eg: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)

Comment: If you use C#, then you can do group in LINQ.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098601/java-count-occurrence-of-each-item-in-an-array

Comment: Effort on your part please...

Answer (score 1):

The logic for this task could be as follow:

For each element in array `a`

1. check if element was previously used (may create array `b` to add unique element)
   1.1 If it was used `continue`, otherwise add to array `b`
2. initialize counter and currentIndex variables
3. Search and count number of occurrences from the currentIndex, while currentIndex value is not `-1`
4. Print the element and its counter

Comment: Why exactly aren't YOU doing that @EthanParker?