# Check how many times a String appears in a String[]

Tags: android, arrays, string

In my Android app I have a `String[]` initialized like this:

```
String[] array = {"abc", "def", "abc", "ghi", "def", "def"};
```

How can I check how many times every String appears in the `String[]`? For example, `"abc"` appears 2 times, `"def"` appears 3 times, and `"ghi"` appears only once.

I'll appriciate it if you'll help me to figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098601/java-count-occurrence-of-each-item-in-an-array

Comment: I suggest you try to do your own homework first.

Answer (score 1):

Check this :

```
public int checkOccurrence(String word, String [] array){

    int count=0;

    for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++){

        if(word.equals(array[i]))
            count++;
    }

    return count;
}
```