# Count the occurrences of successive items in an array

Tags: java, arrays, counting

Let's assume the `items` array consists of the following items `{3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.2, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4, 3.4, 3.4, 3.4, 3.1, 3.1}`

What I want is to count the occurrence of each item in the successive items such that:

```
3.1 = 3 
3.2 = 2
3.3 = 1
3.4 = 4
3.1 = 2
```

I wrote the following function:

```
private void displayItems(List<Double> items) {
        double current_item=0;
        for(int i=0; i<items.size(); i++) {
            int count=1;
            current_item = items.get(i);
            if(i != items.size()) {
                for(int j=i+1; j<items.size(); j++) {
                    double next_item = items.get(j);
                    if(current_item == next_item) {
                        count++;
                    }else {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("item value is " + current_item + " and count is " + count);
            }
        }
    }
```

I got the following result:

```
item value is 3.1 and count is 3
item value is 3.1 and count is 2
item value is 3.1 and count is 1
item value is 3.2 and count is 2
item value is 3.2 and count is 1
item value is 3.3 and count is 1
item value is 3.4 and count is 4
item value is 3.4 and count is 3
item value is 3.4 and count is 2
item value is 3.4 and count is 1
item value is 3.1 and count is 2
item value is 3.1 and count is 1
```

What can I do to show the results like the following:

```
item value is 3.1 and count is 3
item value is 3.2 and count is 2
item value is 3.3 and count is 1
item value is 3.4 and count is 4
item value is 3.1 and count is 2
```

Please not that I don't want to count the occurrence of each item in the entire array, I just want to count its occurrence in the successive items only.

Comment: To count successive items there should 'probably' only be a single loop.

Comment: I think you should loop through the array once, and store the items in a float indexed map, then the value would just be the count.

Comment: @Fallenreaper OP wants to count runs, not totals. (See last line of expected result.)

Comment: @user2864740 I couldn't do it with a single loop

Comment: @AdamAmin I'm saying: it's possible, and will likely lead to the desired result :) Imagine if this setup was given (assuming that `items.size() > 0`): `current_item = items.get(0); for (int i = 1; i < items.size(); i++) { .. }`. There are too many items in the current output because the outer loop is effectively solving the problem 'for every different starting position'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java count occurrence of each item in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098601/java-count-occurrence-of-each-item-in-an-array)

Comment: This is **not** a duplicate of *that* question ("Java count occurrence of each item in an array"). See the expected output.

Comment: Same concept with sub-lists.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas The OP is asking for how to "count the size of runs (of the same value)". This is not solvable with (trivial) use of Sets or Maps, because Sets and Maps cannot contain duplicates. The other question is about counting total counts.

Comment: Are you trying to count the occurrences of each object by identity or by value? By this, I mean `new Double(3.14) != new Double(3.14)`. If you are checking values, rather than identities, then you should use `equals` instead of `==`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is iterating over the values which were already counted in the previous iterations. A small tweak in the logic works as expected.

```
private void displayItems(List<Double> items) {
        double current_item=0;
        for(int i=0; i<items.size(); i++) {
            int count=1;
            current_item = items.get(i);
            if(i != items.size()) {
                int j=i+1;
                for(; j<items.size(); j++) {
                    double next_item = items.get(j);
                    if(current_item == next_item) {
                        count++;
                    }else {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("item value is " + current_item + " and count is " + count);
                i = j-1;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
x[n-1]-x[n]==0
```

should be the formula.

```
public class SuccessiveCounter {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        double[] x = {3.1,3.1,3.1,3.2,3.2,3.1,3.1,3.4,3.4,3.1,3.1};

        for(int n=1,count = 1;n<x.length;n++){
            if(x[n-1]-x[n]==0){
                count++;
            }else{
                System.out.println(x[n]+" "+count);
                count = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a map to map the double to how many times it occurs. Then simply loop over the map to print the values.

```
private static void count(List<Double> numbers)
{
    final Map<Double, Integer> numberToOccurrences = new HashMap<>();
    for(Double num : numbers)
    {
        numberToOccurrences.putIfAbsent(num, 0);
        numberToOccurrences.compute(num, (k, occurrences) -> ++occurrences);
    }
    numberToOccurrences.forEach((num, occurrences) -> 
        System.out.println("Number " + num + " occurs " + occurrences + " times")
    );
}
```

A few uses of lambdas here which may be considered more advanced, but they often result in the the most concise solution.

Comment: This will count the total number of items in the list `Number 3.1 occurs 5 times` however the desired output is `3.1 = 3 
3.2 = 2
3.3 = 1
3.4 = 4
3.1 = 2`

Answer (score 1):

I guess all the above answers are correct but I also wanted to try this with single loop so here it is with single loop:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class SuccessiveCount {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Double> list = Arrays.asList(3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.2, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4, 3.4, 3.4, 3.4, 3.1, 3.1);
        double prevValue = list.get(0);
        int count = 0;
        for(int i=0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if(prevValue == list.get(i)) {
                count++;
            }else {
                System.out.println("item value is "+list.get(i-1)+ " and count is "+ count);
                prevValue = list.get(i);
                count = 1;
            }
            if(list.size() == (i+1)) {
                System.out.println("item value is "+list.get(i-1)+ " and count is "+ count);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

PS : If anyone wants to make it look more cleaner I am up for suggestions.

Comment: @zawhtut nice touch with formula :)

Answer (score 0):

What about making an `ArrayList<String>`?

```
ArrayList<String> runs = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Then storing something like

```
runs.add(current_item + "," + count);
```

instead of your print line,
Then going through the array list and split each string by the comma to get desired output.

While it may work it is probably not ideal, but still a possible solution.

EDIT: You would go through runs after the nested loop

Comment: This is appropriate as an answer.  You shouldn't comment for something like this.

Comment: It started as a comment then became an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Here are the changes,

```
int dec = 0;
int inc = 0;
if(current_item == next_item) {
     count++;
     dec = count; //new line
}
else {
     break;
}
}
//new stuff from here, printing "inc" instead of "count" in print statement.
dec--;
inc++;
if(dec==0){
    System.out.println("item value is " + current_item + " and count is " + inc);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will give the expected result

```
int count = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
            if (i != 0) {
                if (arr.get(i) - arr.get(i - 1) == 0) {
                    count++;
                } else if (arr.get(i) - arr.get(i - 1) != 0) {
                    System.out.println("Item value is " + arr.get(i - 1) + " and count is " + count);
                    count = 1;
                }
            }
            if (arr.size() == i + 1) {
                System.out.println("Item value is " + arr.get(i) + " and count is " + count);
            }
        }
```