# Counting the Occurrence of a String in an Array of Strings

Tags: java

I figured out how to count the occurrence of all the strings expect one of them because I am using indexOf because I haven't learned anything new in this class that I'm taking so I was wondering if I can get help here is the code. (Not able to count the Bolded "cat")

```
class Main {


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] arr= {"Catcat", "Dogsaregoodcatsarebetter", "Ilovecatcat", "Goatsarecutetoo"};
    System.out.println(countOccurence2(arr, "cat"));
    System.out.println(countOccurence2(arr, "cute"));
    System.out.println(countOccurence2(arr, "horse"));

  }


  public static int countOccurence2(String[]arr, String n)

  {

        int count = 0;


        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            if(arr[i].indexOf(n) != -1)
            {

               count++;


            }
        }
        return count;
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it what u want? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098601/java-count-occurrence-of-each-item-in-an-array

Comment: What output do you get when you run your program? What output do you expect instead?

Comment: Output I get: 3, 1, 0

Output I need 4, 1, 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `indexOf` to count all occurrences of a string, but you have to use the [form](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-int-int-) that takes the index at which to start counting, which will be the previously found index plus the length of the query string.

```
public static int countOccurence2(String[]arr, String n)
{
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
      int idx = arr[i].indexOf(n);
      while(idx != -1)
      {
        count++;
        idx = arr[i].indexOf(n, idx+n.length());
      }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Which produces the desired output: 4,1,0

Answer (score 1):

Try using this

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

 public static int countOccurence2(String[]arr, String n) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(n.toLowerCase());
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        Matcher m = p.matcher(arr[i].toLowerCase());
        while (m.find()) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
 }
```

What it does is that it uses [regular expression](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm) to match a pattern in the given string. And I think `toLowerCasse()` is a self-explanatory method, no need to give an explanation for it.

If you want it to be case-sensitive, just remove the `toLowerCase()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#countMatches(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

```
  /**
   * <p>Counts how many times the substring appears in the larger string.</p>
   *
   * <p>A {@code null} or empty ("") String input returns {@code 0}.</p>
   *
   * <pre>
   * StringUtils.countMatches(null, *)       = 0
   * StringUtils.countMatches("", *)         = 0
   * StringUtils.countMatches("abba", null)  = 0
   * StringUtils.countMatches("abba", "")    = 0
   * StringUtils.countMatches("abba", "a")   = 2
   * StringUtils.countMatches("abba", "ab")  = 1
   * StringUtils.countMatches("abba", "xxx") = 0
   * </pre>
   *
   * @param str  the CharSequence to check, may be null
   * @param sub  the substring to count, may be null
   * @return the number of occurrences, 0 if either CharSequence is {@code null}
   * @since 3.0 Changed signature from countMatches(String, String) to countMatches(CharSequence, CharSequence)
   */
  public static int countMatches(final CharSequence str, final CharSequence sub) {
      if (isEmpty(str) || isEmpty(sub)) {
          return 0;
      }
      int count = 0;
      int idx = 0;
      while ((idx = CharSequenceUtils.indexOf(str, sub, idx)) != INDEX_NOT_FOUND) {
          count++;
          idx += sub.length();
      }
      return count;
  }

  /**
   * Used by the indexOf(CharSequence methods) as a green implementation of indexOf.
   *
   * @param cs the {@code CharSequence} to be processed
   * @param searchChar the {@code CharSequence} to be searched for
   * @param start the start index
   * @return the index where the search sequence was found
   */
  static int indexOf(final CharSequence cs, final CharSequence searchChar, final int start) {
      return cs.toString().indexOf(searchChar.toString(), start);
  }
```

Comment: I am trying to find only the lower case cat's so n is set to "cat" I don't need Cat.

So the Error is at "Ilovecatcat" I get the first "cat" but not the second "cat", and I don't know how to use indexOf to get it since It only gets the first occurrence.

Output: 3, 1, 0 when returning count; Answer: 4, 1, 0

Comment: @Arrow Updated answer